# Can't understand words from video

Tags: listening

I'm currently translating this interview and have a problem with understanding words from 17:45 to 17:50 in this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0iaG0RN37k (Warning: the video contains language that some may find offensive)

After "I invent the eviliest thing I possibly could put on my face. Constructed of leather..." and to "Put it all together". It's about materials he used to make the mask, but nothing I'm familiar with or can recognize.
Thank you for your attention, maybe you could help me.

Comment: me neither & I'm english

Comment: Me neither and I'm American.  They could be made up.

Comment: @snailboat he also said (hut/hot/hutt) - what could it possibly mean?

Comment: @snailboat - that's actually what I thought he said, but it made little sense to me, so I copped out ;)

Comment: @YevgenyPotapov he's actually saying 'Ming the Merciless hat' The one Max von Sydow wore in Flash Gordon.

Comment: @JoeDark Thanks, I made an answer based on your comment.  It seems obviously true in retrospect, but somehow I missed it the first couple times.

Comment: @JoeDark listening to his pronunciation - is it likely that he would pronounce "hat" like that? Are you sure?

Comment: @YevgenyPotapov I'm 100% positive. I suspect the long pause between merciless and hat is because he didn't want to call it a hat but couldn't think of anything else. It's more of a skullcap than a hat.

Comment: @JoeDark Yep, I watched this moment to catch the intonation and I understand it the same way as you now. 
I'm currently on 20:30 and can't recognize what the guy said after "...relax, you know, get that out of my system and go to bed". I guess it's the only thing left in this video that I can't understand.

Comment: 20:30 *...So, you know, I owe a lot to music, and especially to metal music.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summing up the comments section:

> I invent the evilest thing I possibly could put on my face, constructed of leather, cop shades, a chrome Ming the Merciless hat. Put it all together, can't see shit, can't breathe, can't – can't feel, can't do anything, very painful.  That was a personal pain.

Thanks to Joe Dark for convincing me that it was *hat* rather than *hot*.

Comment: Could you please listen to this moment in video - Is this even a word on 22:15 - "The fifth record - the most beautiful..."?